# Monoid action on an uncountably infinite set

Tags: ct.category-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

The action of a monoid on a finite set is equivalent to a finite state machine, however I would like a categorical way to think about an uncountably infinite state machine (a state transition system?).
My question is -- Can I think about such a system as the action of a monoid on an uncountably infinite set?  Is it that easy to extend this idea?

(Behind my question is my study of the performance of a particle accelerator.  I am thinking about the Hamiltonian phase space of each particle as the "state" of the system, with this state being acted on by by a sequence of beamline elements (e.g., magnets, accelerating cavities, etc.).  So the monoid would consist of beamline elements -- with a zero length element acting as the identity, and concatenation of elements acting as the multiplication function.  Each of these will act on the 6xN phase space of the beam (containing N particles) where each coordinate is a real number -- thus uncountably infinite.)

Comment: It seems like your system has much more structure than a plain uncountable set.  For example, phase space should be a symplectic manifold, and a space of quantum states should be a vector space.

Comment: Thanks S.Carnahan. You're right -- the system state (particle phase space) is a symplectic manifold -- and I would like to thank you for this insight.  In accelerator physics, we work mostly with classical Hamiltonian dynamics, and quantum states rarely play a role.
My question still remains, although perhaps with different words -- can I think about this as the action of a monoid on the uncountably infinite phase space of the beam?

Comment: Yes, a set of abstract transformations of a space always generates a monoid action.  Unless there are interesting relations between the compositions, it's not clear that you gain anything by thinking of the monoid, though.  I don't see the "state machine" language used in this domain much.

Comment: I'm thinking of how to categorise the study of particle dynamics, with the assumption that interesting insights will be gained by doing this exercise. I have a proposed "accelerator" category including a transformation to an ordered set which can then act on the phase space state of a beam. I get the impression that I may be barking up the wrong tree...